# Get GitHub API-Token for organization

Tags: github, jwt, github-api, github-organizations

I have an organization on GitHub with some private repositories and I want to use the GitHub API to access the repositories [releases](https://docs.github.com/de/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-latest-release). How do I get the API key for it?

I have already created a personal access token on my account, but I cannot access the repository with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a deploy key to do that:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys

Comment: is there any way to get a token for the whole organization? Is this possible with an GitHub App?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that for security reasons. if that token leaks you'd expose all your organization's code. If you really need to grant access to all repos, you can generate an ssh key, add it to your account and use it instead.